# bootstrap mega menu, how change to onclick function and drop down item for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change menu drop down for small devices for "onclick" and "drop down" for item1 and item2, problem is drop down menu subs is outside of root nav for mobile?

How change drop down menu subs in inside root nav and on click for mobile?

Source from http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/ydcMQ/

**My edit::**

**HTML:**

```
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Dispute Bills"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown menu-large ">
                <a href="# " class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown ">item 1<b class="caret "></b></a>              
                <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Glyphicons</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Available glyphs</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled "><a href="# ">How to use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Examples</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Dropdowns</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Aligninment options</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Headers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Disabled menu items</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Button groups</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Basic example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Button toolbar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Sizing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Nesting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Vertical variation</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Button dropdowns</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Single button dropdowns</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Input groups</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Basic example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Sizing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Navs</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Tabs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Pills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Justified</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Navbar</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Default navbar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Text</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Non-nav links</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Component alignment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Fixed to top</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Static top</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Inverted navbar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </li>

            <li class="dropdown menu-large ">
                <a href="# " class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown ">item 2 <b class="caret "></b></a>             
                <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row ">
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Glyphicons</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Available glyphs</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled "><a href="# ">How to use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Examples</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Dropdowns</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Aligninment options</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Headers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Disabled menu items</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Button groups</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Basic example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Button toolbar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Sizing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Nesting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Vertical variation</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Button dropdowns</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Single button dropdowns</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Input groups</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Basic example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Sizing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
                            <li class="divider "></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Navs</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Tabs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Pills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Justified</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header ">Navbar</li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Default navbar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Text</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Non-nav links</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Component alignment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Fixed to top</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Static top</a></li>
                            <li><a href="# ">Inverted navbar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <script>
// Dropdown Menu Fade    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown ").hover(
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast ");
        },
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast ");
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    width: auto;
}


/* This should be around line 4713 in your bootstrap.css */

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.navbar-default {
    color: #0A0A0A;
    background-color: #FFFCFC;
    border-color: rgba(208, 174, 174, 1.00);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #030303;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #7C7373;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #666666;
    border-bottom-color: #111222;
}

.menu-large {
    position: static !important;
}

.megamenu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    float: none;
}

.megamenu> li > ul {
    padding: 0;
}

.megamenu> li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
}

.megamenu> li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333333;
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
}

.megamenu> li ul > li > a:hover,
.megamenu> li ul > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AB2F2F;
    background-color: #EFE7E7;
}

.megamenu.disabled > a,
.megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
.megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
    color: #9A5455;
}

.megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
.megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.dropdown-header {
    color: #1D5586;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #030303;
        padding-right: 1px;
        padding-left: 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        text-align: left;
        /* Set this */
    }
    .megamenu {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .megamenu> li {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .megamenu> li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .megamenu.dropdown-header {
        padding: 3px 15px !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

my code on:  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jaman7/6wbvk8ed/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a{
  background : transparent !important;
 }

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu{
  background : white;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header{
  color : #999999 !important;
}
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcMQ/898/)